Generate aliased namespaced tags with Ctags
I'm trying to configure Universal Ctags to recognize functions imported from different namespaces with an alias. The language I'm using is Clojure (I also give an example in Javascript), so every module has its own namespace and it's very common to assign alias to those namespaces when requiring them. An example would be
(ns my.module)

(defn my-fn []
  "hello world")

(ns my.main.path
  (:require
    [my.module :as mod]))

;; Local fn not used in this file
(defn my-fn []
  "say hi")

(defn main []
  (mod/my-fn))

My expectation is that when I put the cursor over mod/my-fn and jump to definition, it jumps to my-fn defined in my.module.
When I run ctags -R this is the generated tags file
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION anonymous   /Include tags for non-named objects like lambda/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION fileScope   /Include tags of file scope/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION pseudo  /Include pseudo tags/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION subparser   /Include tags generated by subparsers/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION epoch   /the last modified time of the input file (only for F\/file kind tag)/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION file    /File-restricted scoping/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION input   /input file/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION name    /tag name/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION pattern /pattern/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION typeref /Type and name of a variable or typedef/
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!Clojure  a,namespacealias    /namespacealias/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!Clojure  f,function  /functions/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!Clojure  n,namespace /namespaces/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!Clojure  v,variable  /variable/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_EXCMD  mixed   /number, pattern, mixed, or combineV2/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_FILESEP    slash   /slash or backslash/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_VERSION    0.0 /current.age/
!_TAG_PARSER_VERSION!Clojure    0.0 /current.age/
!_TAG_PATTERN_LENGTH_LIMIT  96  /0 for no limit/
!_TAG_PROC_CWD  /home/jp/clj-tmp/   //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   6.1.0   /7cc5308a4/
main    my/main/path.clj    /^(defn main []$/;" f
main    my/main/path.clj    /^(defn main []$/;" f   namespace:my.main.path
my-fn   my/main/path.clj    /^(defn my-fn []$/;"    f
my-fn   my/main/path.clj    /^(defn my-fn []$/;"    f   namespace:my.main.path
my-fn   my/module.clj   /^(defn my-fn []$/;"    f
my-fn   my/module.clj   /^(defn my-fn []$/;"    f   namespace:my.module
my.main.path    my/main/path.clj    /^(ns my.main.path$/;"  n
my.module   my/module.clj   /^(ns my.module)$/;"    n

To give this same example in a more common language, here it is javascript
// module.js
export function greet() {
    console.log('Hello, world!');
}

// main.js
import * as myModule from './module';

function greet() {
    console.log('hi, world!');
}

myModule.greet();

!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION anonymous   /Include tags for non-named objects like lambda/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION fileScope   /Include tags of file scope/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION pseudo  /Include pseudo tags/
!_TAG_EXTRA_DESCRIPTION subparser   /Include tags generated by subparsers/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION epoch   /the last modified time of the input file (only for F\/file kind tag)/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION file    /File-restricted scoping/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION input   /input file/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION name    /tag name/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION pattern /pattern/
!_TAG_FIELD_DESCRIPTION typeref /Type and name of a variable or typedef/
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!Ctags    k,kind  /kind definitions/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!Ctags    l,langdef   /language definitions/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   C,constant  /constants/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   G,getter    /getters/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   M,field /fields/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   S,setter    /setters/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   c,class /classes/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   f,function  /functions/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   g,generator /generators/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   m,method    /methods/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   p,property  /properties/
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript   v,variable  /global variables/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_EXCMD  mixed   /number, pattern, mixed, or combineV2/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_FILESEP    slash   /slash or backslash/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_VERSION    0.0 /current.age/
!_TAG_PARSER_VERSION!Ctags  0.0 /current.age/
!_TAG_PARSER_VERSION!JavaScript 1.1 /current.age/
!_TAG_PATTERN_LENGTH_LIMIT  96  /0 for no limit/
!_TAG_PROC_CWD  /home/jp/js-tmp/    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   6.1.0   /7cc5308a4/
!_TAG_ROLE_DESCRIPTION!JavaScript!function  foreigndecl /declared in foreign languages/
alias   js.ctags    /^--regex-javascript=\/^[ \\t]*import \\* as ([^ \\t,]+) from[ \\t]+[\\'"][^\\'"]+[\\'"]\/\\1\/a,a/;"   k
function    js.ctags    /^--regex-javascript=\/^[ \\t]*export[ \\t]+function[ \\t]+([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*)\/\\1\/f,func/;"   k
greet   main.js /^function greet() {$/;"    f
greet   module.js   /^export function greet() {$/;" f


I know that Universal Ctags has become a very different beast than the original but I doubt that what you want is possible because, AFAIK, it still parses files in isolation, without keeping track of some global context like a compiler would. It should be possible to create a my.module.my_fn tag, for example, which could work in absence of renaming. But the mod renaming happens in another file, which the parser is not aware of at the time of parsing. Anyway, that's a question for the project's support channel, not for SO.

Hum.. I might indeed be in the wrong track. My end goal is not using the tags file for jumping to definition. I need a solution able to map definitions and usages in a language agnostic way.
